# Multi-Organization Architecture Play2Java+Heroku+Postgres

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0, multi-tenant, postgresql-9.4

I have an application developed on heroku cloud. Restful application developed with Play2 framework for Java, using Postgres database.

Scenario: organization1 and organization2 would like to access the application on same url (like login.salesforce.com). Of course, users from organization1 should only see their data, users from oeganization2 theirs. I do not want to make application instance for every organization.

What is the best way to handle it? Simply by having entity organization and then using organizations Id in other enthities as foreign keys? Any other approaches?

Comment: Are you using JPA (Hibernate) as your persistence provider. Then, you can use Hibernate's multi-tenant capabilities which switches the `Datasource` dynamically based on a tenant id resolver. I have put together a working example which works with Play + MySQL + Hibernate.. but it should not be too different for Postgres. https://github.com/rajendrag/play-jpa-multitenant

Comment: Yes, I am using and will take a look, thank!

Comment: As far as I can see you have separated databases per organization? And of course, one common database?

Comment: Yes.. There are other approaches like having one database and a discriminator column in each table but I feel that might be more difficult to manage.

Comment: Yes i guess so. But the problem with many databases is cost issue for me as each database would require heroku paid plan...

Comment: I think you can go ahead with one database and multiple schemas approach, you don't really need to manage multiple databases. One database with multiple schemas and each schema is almost works like a different database.